# Assign different ViewModels to one UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I have MainWindow.xaml page with it's MainViewModel
and would like to add 2 SidePanels using one UserControl, but it should have different ViewModels. 
MainViewModel alredy has 2 properties with created SidePanelViewModels:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    LeftSidePanel = new SidePanelViewModel(PanelSides.Left);
    RightSidePanel = new SidePanelViewModel(PanelSides.Right);
}
```

How to set objects in this properties as DataContext for each UserControl in xaml?
Something like this doesnot work:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding RightSidePanel.PanelVisibility}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" >
        <v:SidePanelViev DataContext="{Binding RightSidePanel}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I broke all the brains thinking how to do it, Please help

ps.
Or please suggest any other approach to reach the same target..

Comment: What is your problem? What you've shown should work.

Comment: But it does not, when i am trying to bind any property in user control, properties window of the user control shows that it does not have Data Context

Comment: Wild guess but in `UserControl` constructor do you do something like `DataContext = this`?

Comment: You was right, approach, mentioned above, also works despite the fact that IntelliSense and properties window of the user control do not see that user control have Data Context. If carefully copy and paste correct property from viewmodel to the binding in usercontrol, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by adding both instances of SidePanelViewModel as Content of ContentControl

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding RightSidePanel.PanelVisibility}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" >
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RightSidePanel}"></ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and adding new Window.Resource what binds all classes of type SidePanelViewModel to be visualised using SidePanelViev

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SidePanelViewModel}">
        <v:SidePanelViev></v:SidePanelViev>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This works, but if somebody has better ideas, please do not hesitate to post them, I am not sure that my decision is good one